# How to match a self repeating pattern using regex

Tags: regex

I’m wondering if it’s possible to use regex to find all occurrences of a repeating string in another string

For a simple example find aaa in aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

If I’ve counted properly it happens 13 times so an answer that finds 13 rather than 5 occourances would be good.

Another example

abcabc in abcabcabcabc where it repeats 3 times

Comment: Are you using a programming language here, or is this more of an abstract regex question?

Comment: just enclose the pattern in a group and put a quantifier? `(abc)+` Although the *number* of repeats will not be explicitly output. Depends on where you're using it - in a programming language, you're likely to be able to match the pattern ibce until you exhaust all matches, so you'll have to keep a counter.

Comment: Yes @Tim I’m using Swift i was thinking the solution would be to solve this puzzle then use numberOfMatches(in:options:range:) to count the ocourances

Comment: Thanks @Toto I don’t know why I didn’t find this answer in my searching. It looks like the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

If the regex engine of your chosen programming language or tool supports positive lookaheads?
Then you could use that.

A javascript example that counts 13 "aaa" in the sample string:

```
var str = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
var re = /(?=(aaa))/g;

var total = str.match(re).length;
console.log(total);
```

An other example, which counts 3 "abcabc":

```
var str = "abcabcabcabc";
var searchString = "abcabc";
var re = new RegExp("(?=("+searchString+"))", "g");

var total = str.match(re).length;
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually i would go for quantifiers like `(aaa)+` or if you know the specific length then `(aaa){5}` or if you need it a minimum of 5 times then `(aaa){5,}` or a maximum of 5 `(aaa){,5}` or a minimum of 5 and maximum of 10 like this `(aaa){5,10}`.

If you are unsure if any matches are in there, then you can also go for "0 or more" which would be (aaa)*

As a hinter, you can match IPv4 Adresses (badly) like this:

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.?){4}
```

**do not use this in production for matching IPs, this is just to illustrate a repeating pattern :)**

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: The question before it got edited.

Comment: But, I don't see any edit to this question ???

Comment: it says "edited yesterday", roughly a few hours after i posted this and two hours before you started baffing at me :)

Comment: FYI: Question asked `2019-10-27 13:02:37Z` without any update later, your answer `2016-10-27 13:08:21Z`